# How do I set JSP UseBean values from a servlet

Tags: jsp, session, tomcat, jakarta-ee, javabeans

I am writing a web application that uses a JSP usebean tag in the session scope as shown below

```
<jsp:useBean id="userSession" class="project.session.UserSession" scope="session" />
```

I have also written a filter which does some processing and needs to set some values on the userSession bean. How do I get a handle onto the object and set values on it? I have tried getting the object from session as shown below, but this method doesn't work.

```
UserSession userSession = (UserSession)request.getSession().getAttribute("userSession");
```

I use Tomcat for development.

Comment: Your filter runs before your JSP does. I assume you are referring to access the bean after you have set it (i.e. another request). Is the session valid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is null (it will always be on the **first** request), then you just need to precreate it yourself.

```
UserSession userSession = (UserSession) request.getSession().getAttribute("userSession");
if (userSession == null) {
    userSession = new UserSession();
    request.getSession().setAttribute("userSession", userSession);
}
userSession.doSomething();
```

Comment: A small change to the setAttribute though. I was able to get this working by removing the attribute from session first and then adding the newly created session attribute.